# Retrive List data from resultset and Convert into JSON

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, rest, resultset

I am new to json. I want to get all the values from ResultSet and set it to proper JSON format. I didn't get it how to solve this problem. I have tried many things from stackoverflow but I am unable to solve this problem. Please anyone help me to get out of this.

```
String query = "SELECT emp_id, code, salary  FROM emp_tbl";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
    emp_id = rs.getString("emp_id");
    code = rs.getString("code");
    salary = rs.getString("salary");

    list.add("emp_id");
    list.add("code");
    list.add("salary");
    jsonarray = new JSONArray(list);
}
System.out.println("jsonarray: "+jsonarray);
```

This is the output:

```
jsonarray: ["1","5563","11000", "2","5463","14000", "3","9847","9000"]
```

But it should be like this

```
[
  {
    "emp_id": "1",
    "code": "5563",
    "salary": 11000
  }, {
    "emp_id": "2",
    "code": "5463",
    "salary": 14000
  }
]
```

If i tried this

```
while (rs.next()) {                 
    emp_id = rs.getString("emp_id");
    code = rs.getString("code");
    salary= rs.getString("salary");
    jsonarray.put("emp_id");
    jsonarray.put("code ");
    jsonarray.put("salary");
} 
System.out.println("jsonarray: "+jsonarray);
```

then the output is

```
jsonarray: {"emp_id":"5","code":"526","salary":"10000"}
```

It only gets last row, but not all values.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html:

```
   JsonArray arr = Json.createArrayBuilder()
             .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                 .add("type", "home")
                 .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
             .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                 .add("type", "fax")
                 .add("number", "646 555-4567"))
             .build();

   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   JsonWriter writer = Json.createWriter(baos);
   writer.writeArray(arr);
   writer.close();

   String str = baos.toString();
```

generates this output:
[{"type":"home","number":"212 555-1234"},{"type":"fax","number":"646 555-4567"}]

Answer (score 0):

Return a json array of objects from the query:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(emp_tbl)) as my_json
from (values
    ('1','5563',11000),
    ('2','5463',14000)      
) emp_tbl (emp_id, code, salary)
;
                                          my_json                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"emp_id":"1","code":"5563","salary":11000}, {"emp_id":"2","code":"5463","salary":14000}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but as far as I understood, that it will return json array. But my problem is that How to make this query dynamic. I am trying to execute like this `select json_agg(row_to_json(emp_tbl)) from (values (emp_id, code, salary)) emp_tbl (emp_id, code, salary);` But it shows `column name emp_id is not found`

Comment: @rockroyal Give the column an alias as I did in the update: `as my_json`

Comment: In instead of `from (values...` use `from emp_tbl`. I used `values` just to fill in some sample values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. `SELECT json_agg(ROW.*) FROM (SELECT emp_id, code, salary FROM emp_tbl)ROW;` this works for me.